# NETWORK_PROVIDER doesn't work in Galaxy Young?

Tags: android

I have an application where I use `isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`
But when I put this app in Samsung Galaxy Young, it always returns `false` even the  option `Packet Data` is enabled in Settings.

Why could be wrong?

This is part of my code:

```
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    locationManager = (LocationManager) c
            .getSystemService(this.c.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // getting network status
    isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

Toast.makeText(c.getApplicationContext(), "Obteniendo network provider = "+isNetworkEnabled, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (isNetworkEnabled) { 
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "obtiene localizaciones de network provider NET.... ");
        ret = 0;
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) c
                .getSystemService(c.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        myloc = null;
        myloc = new mylocationlistener();
        LocationListener locationListener = myloc;
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "myloc.... latitude=" + myloc.getLatitude()
                + " Longitude=" + myloc.getLongitud());
        Toast.makeText(c.getApplicationContext(), "conectandose AGPS...lat = "+myloc.getLatitude()+ " Longitud = "+myloc.getLongitud(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                locationListener);                  
    } else {

        ret = -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure to enable Location services?  You can configure this via the Settings application (under Personal on my S3).

Comment: Thanks. I enabled the Option

Comment: Ok thanks.. I enabled the opton USE WIRELESS and it works.. Now the problem is get Location.... my class (related to the code above) is:

Comment: I'm a little confused about the exact problem.  Could you please be a little more specific?  Are you not getting any location updates?

Also, have you made sure to add the correct permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml?  See Android's Developer Guide for [location strategies and permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Permission).

Comment: For NETWORK_PROVIDER, you need to have the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission defined in your AndroidManifest.xml.  Add the following:     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> and see if that helps.